# Is there anyway to display line break in view with single char field in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I got a problem with displaying line break. I have a char field:

```
log = fields.Char(string='Log')
```

Then I set the value of this field is "This is my code\nAn example"

I want to display in my formview like

```
This is my code

An example
```

But actually, the result is: "This is my codeAn example"

This is my code in xml:

```
<field name="log"/>
```

Comment: What about using `fields.Text`? Char fields aren't made for line breaks.

Comment: I tried with fields.Text, but the same result. Any solution to make line break in single field?